# Logical short circuiting in SQL Server 2008 seems to fail for the CONTAINS full text predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains, full-text-search

I have a pretty complicated query which sometimes returns results very slowly. It was clear from the beginning that the culprit is the part of the WHERE clause that has to do with full text search. So I isolated it and tested. This testing resulted in figuring out when it happens, but I so far failed to figure out how I can fix it. Here is what the problem is:

I need to filter on one, two or three full-text indexed columns based on what the user wants to do. Since it seems that the column list within the CONTAINS predicate cannot be suplied as variable the next best thing I could come up with is to employ some standard boolean logic like so:

```
(((@SearchInName = 0 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 0 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 0) OR @SearchExpression = '""')
OR (@SearchInName = 1 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 0 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 0 AND CONTAINS(ProductName, @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 0 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 1 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 0 AND CONTAINS(ProductShortDescr, @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 0 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 0 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 1 AND CONTAINS(ProductDescrHTML, @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 1 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 1 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 0 AND CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductShortDescr), @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 1 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 0 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 1 AND CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductDescrHTML), @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 0 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 1 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 1 AND CONTAINS((ProductShortDescr, ProductDescrHTML), @SearchExpression))
OR (@SearchInName = 1 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 1 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 1 AND CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductShortDescr, ProductDescrHTML), @SearchExpression))
```

That would be fine and works as expected (fast) as long as the actual valid condition matches the last OR section. So in the example above it would be when @SearchInName = 1 AND @SearchInShortDescr = 1 AND @SearchInHTMLDescr = 1 (the user is wants to search in all 3 columns). The other conditions ALSO return quickly if they are put last within this code block. However, as soon as the actual valid condition is higher than last, it seems that all the CONTAINS statements following it are run as well (not necessarily included in the results though, which is correct) which takes the execution time from under 1s to 6 seconds or more depending on how high the valid statement is and therefore how many other CONTAINS predicates follow. The obvious conclusion from this is that for some reason the following boolean statements fail to short-circuit and run the CONTAINS predicate regardless.

I understand that the order of execution is not always given by the actual code and that after SQL optimization some short circuiting may not work as designed thanks to it, which seems to be this case. The suggestion there usually is to use the CASE statement to ensure the order, but unfortunately the CONTAINS statement does not seem to be happy within a CASE statement at all.

So I think I probably kind of know why it is happening (the SQL optimization), but cannot figure out a way how to actually fix this. Can anyone help?

Comment: There's *no* guarantee on which predicates will be evaluated and when, even if using a `CASE` (I used to believe `CASE` could be used to impose ordering, but it turns out not to be so)

Comment: Since this seems to be search related, you might want to read Erland Sommarskog's excellent [Dynamic Search conditions in SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Well, as far as I tested 'CASE' cannot be used with CONTAINS anyway, but thanks for the note.

Comment: Thanks for the link, too. I just finished reading it and there were a couple of new useful points for me. Chiefly it persuaded me about the apparent fact that dynamic SQL is not as "evil" as I believed since a time long time ago. I may need to resort to that with these procs unless someone can help with a better suggestion. I just don't really want to do it since these selects are like 400 lines long and therefore it is nice to get color coding when updating them.

Answer (score 1):

Sql server will cache the plan so it can be reused.   The immediate implication is that the plan SQL server creates has to work for all cases and therefore must be generic.  This eliminates any possibility of short circuiting logic.

One solution is to use the OPTION (RECOMPILE) query hint.  This will force SQL server to recompile the query each time it's executed. Because SQL knows that the plan will never be reused, it will inspect the values of parameters, apply short circuit logic, choose filtered indexes, and make the best possible plan.

This isn't a horrible solution because full text indexes generate partial recompiles anyway (you can get a different plan depending on the query passed to the CONTAINS function).

The alternative is to use dynamic SQL to build the query.  With dynamic SQL you'll get the best of both worlds: better plans and plan reuse.

Does it matter which technique you use?   In most cases, no, either is fine.  If your query is being called very frequently, for example, 3-4 million calls/day, then the number of compilations/sec could become a bottleneck. If that happens, the dynamic SQL approach is advantageous.